# Truffle test: inputting an uint256 outputs a different result

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test, overflow, integers

To simplify my question, let's say I have a Test.sol with a function that simply output the input:

```
function testFunc(uint256 value) public pure returns (uint256) {
  return value;
}
```

Now I want to test it in truffle

```
it('uint input test', async () => {
  var test = await Test.deployed()
  res = await test.testFunc.call(0x10000000000000000000000000000001)
  console.log(res)
  console.log(res.toNumber())
  console.log(res.toString(16))
  assert.equal(res, 0x10000000000000000000000000000001, 'wrong')
})
```

I'm expecting the result should be same as the input, but it fails the assert. Outputs:

```
BigNumber { s: 1, e: 37, c: [ 2126764793, 25586540000000 ] }
2.1267647932558654e+37
1000000000000001d172c5f60ac00000
```

So `0x10000000000000000000000000000001` is changed to `0x1000000000000001d172c5f60ac00000`, I assume it's the JavaScript number overflow problem?

It causes problem when I try to test the bit operations, such as checking ERC721 token ID. How can I bypass it?

Comment: The problem is javascript numbers do not have enough precision. Either compare them as `BigNumers` (the objects returned by web3js), or transform them into strings and compare the as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not be an exact answer, it works when using chai promise:

```
require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .use(require('chai-bignumber')(BigNumber))
  .should()

...

const res = await test.testFunc.call(0x10000000000000000000000000000001)
res.toString().should.be.equal("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
```